# How to quickly get the focus of the file being editted in VS

Tags: visual-studio

Is there any short-cut or device in Visual Studio to let me quickly get focus on the file I am editing?

I often meet the scenario: after I edit a specific c# file for a while, I suddenly want to search for other files in the same directory hierarchy.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pressing `F7` will set the focus on the code editor, or customize it yourself by overwriting `View.ViewCode`.

You can download a cheat sheet with all the shortcuts from MSDN (mostly for English keyboard layouts):

> - [**Visual C# 2008 Keybinding Reference Poster**](http://www.microsoft.com/downloadS/details.aspx?FamilyID=e5f902a8-5bb5-4cc6-907e-472809749973&displaylang=en)
> - [**Visual Basic 2008 Keybinding Reference Poster**](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=255b8cf1-f6bd-4b55-bb42-dd1a69315833&displaylang=en)
> - [**Visual C++ 2008 Keybinding Reference Poster**](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=4411bbfc-0e3c-42b3-bd05-af1d292c986f&displaylang=en)

Or you can create your own cheat sheet (including all your customizations) using a macro:

> [**How to: List Current Keyboard Shortcut Mappings**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247076%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Hi divo,
Pressing F7 just switches back and forth between Source and Design view, doesn't it?

Comment: Well, with the default C# settings in VS 2008 `F7` is bound to the `View.ViewCode` command which displays the code and sets the focus to the editor window.

Comment: All right. What I originally mean is to get the focus on the file in "Solution Explorer", which is being edited. :P

Comment: Ok, then why didn't you ask that ;-) Just press `Ctrl+W, S` (on an English VS. Btw, that shortcut is also displayed in the `View` menu).

Comment: Hi, it seems not working for me: it'll just save the file (English VS). And I didn't see it view menu. Do you know the command name in keyword in options -> Envir -> keyword?

By the way, I often scoll up/down, collapse directories in "Solution Explorer" while I am editing a file so that I frequently forget which file I was in.

Comment: You must press the `Ctrl+W, S` shortcut the following way: Press and hold `Ctrl`, then press `W`. Keep `Ctrl` still pressed and press `S`. That's how all those double-shortcuts work in VS.

Comment: Hi divo, I found that the "View.SolutionExplorer" turns into Ctrl+Alt+L somehow in my VS. This cannot fully satisfy my need; as you collapse the folder or scroll up/down leaving the edited file out of sight, "Ctrl+Alt+L" doesn't work - it will not automatically focus on the edited file, doesn't it?

Comment: If you are not comfortable using keyboard shortcuts you might better better off using the mouse.

Comment: I'm finding ways to improve my productivity :P

Answer (score 24):

If you have focus on e.g. the solution explorer you can focus on the current source code file by pressing

CTRL+TAB

Comment: Excellent combo for [Whack Whack](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DanielGriffen.WhackWhackTerminal).